# Power Series Solution of $y''+2xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So I've been doing some Power Series Method problems for non constant differentials but I can't seem to get this one.

$$\begin{cases}y'' + 2xy=0, \\y(0)=1 ,\,  y'(0)=1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is an [Airy differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not that different from other power series methods. Suppose $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, then
$$
0=y''+2xy = \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n n(n-1)x^{n-2}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+1}
$$
Making the exponent the same in the sums by changing the dummy variables, we have
$$
0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)x^n+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n=
2a_2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty [a_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)+2a_{n-1}]x^n
$$
Hence $a_2=0$ and
$$
a_{n+2} = - \dfrac{2a_{n-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\Longrightarrow
a_n = - \dfrac{2a_{n-3}}{n(n-1)}
$$
Moreover with your initial boundary conditions $a_0 = a_1 =1$. So you can find all $a_n$ recursively. If $n=3k+r$, denoting by $a(k,r):=a_n$ ($r=0,1$ since $a_{3k+2}=0$ because $a_2=0$), then I calim
$$
a_n= a(k,r) = \dfrac{(-2)^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k (3j+r)(3j+r-1)}
$$
To prove use induction.

Comment: I have not been taught how to use induction.

Comment: It is interesting to notice that there is an explicit formula for $a_n$. Unfortunately or not, it involves  the gamma function.